# Android OpenGL ES 1.1 flickering

Tags: android, opengl-es

While you are promoting my Android project, I discovered a strange.

I can display the map in the ocean Android OpenGL ES 2D graphics.

So, to be used only to determine the phase order of the object, the value is reduced to about 0.0001 Z-axis.

I tried over 1000 times the size of the object In the meantime.

Then, a phenomenon depending on the zoom in / zoom out, **some objects flickering occurred.**

Why such problems occur??

It is the problem of the target terminal-specific this can not be resolved if?

Or is it a problem of Android OpenGL ES itself?

***More....
The photo below is what you screen shot every time the screen of the actual device.

[image]

***I occurs when such a phenomenon to zoom in / zoom out each time.

Comment: Maybe you could attach some screenshots showing the problem?

Comment: Was attached to the main content. Look at the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume what you are experiencing is **z-fighting**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting

This results due to the fact that your objects are too close together so that the z-buffer for certain pixels can't distinguish between which pixel is below or above the other.
You have three choices now:

1) Adjust your projection, specifically adjust **znear** and **zfar** values. Read more here: http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/depthbuffer.htm

2) Increase the distance between both objects

3) Since you are drawing a 2D scene, you might use orthogonal projection. In that case it might be worth not to use depth buffering at all and just draw the objects from back to front (Painters Algorithm, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painters_algorithm).

Comment: Thank you very much flobo~! I'm very apreciate it!!!  I tried to think of three ways.

Comment: The first method, I project is in progress, so you try to view the map, you may need to increase many essential zfar number. I dropped out because (about 100,000 times).

Comment: The second method, since it is necessary to adjust more spacing between objects, both the position of the zoom at the time are skewed. As a result, I dropped out.

Comment: It is a solution still a third way. I will be If you do not see how to apply the algorithm phase relationship with the Cartesian coordinate system from the beginning. ~ Thank you for answer

Comment: Hello JavaHell,
Hmm I do not fully understand your comments, sorry :-)
As far as I understood, you mean that the first two choices are not possible for you. About the third: What do you exactely mean with the Cartesian coordinates? All you have to do is to sort your rendering, that's it :-)